# Selenium firefox profile opening pdf read when pdfjs.disabled is true & adobe reader is installed

Tags: java, firefox, pdf, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download a pdf file using Selenium web driver with Java. This was working fine the last time I run it about 2 weeks ago, but now every time it clicks on the pdf link it is opening the pdf reader.

My firefox profile I create in the test hasn't been changed, it set a download location and sets file to download automatically if they're pdf or csv. The csv files are still working correctly and download to the correct folder.

In my code I have pdfjs.disabled set to true and if I open the about:config in the webdriver firefox instance I can see this is set correctly.

If I set pdfjs.disabled to true in another firefox instance and manually click a link it works correctly.

I'm not sure if firefox has been updated since I last run the test but I have also installed adobe reader on my computer.

Please can anyone tell me what could have made it suddenly stop working?

This is the the profile I create and the way I call the webdriver. I am using Firefox 21.0 which is the latest version.

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

// Set profile to accept untrusted certificates
firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);

//Set profile to not assumet certificate issuer is untrusted
firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

//Set download location and file types
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",reportFolder);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv,application/pdf,application/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel");

// Set to false so popup not displayed when download finished.
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete",false);

firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStartinge",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.useToolkitUI",true);

// Set this to true to disable the pdf opening
firefoxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

**UPDATE: 
I removed adobe reader and this started working again. Reader must set something in the profile that I need to disable to get it working with reader. Does anybody have any ideas?**

Comment: Please see above I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas? It was working fine and nothing has changed apart from the install of adobe reader on my pc and possible an updated firefox.

Comment: I'm not at computer with this code but the report folder works fine. Its set to the current running directory/Reports In this same test I get pdf and csv files, at the end all the csv files are there but the PDFs open in reader. The thing is if I open firefox and set the same profile setting as above and click a pdf it downloads it, it's just the webdriver instance that doesn't work :(

Comment: I have updated the question. This works fine when adobe reader is not installed but I can't guarantee everyone running my test doesn't have this installed. Can anyone suggest what adobe reader is setting in firefox that stops it working?

Comment: Feel free to have a look at [Download PDF files automatically in Firefox using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/05/23/download-pdf-files-automatically-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver/). Setting `plugin.scan.plid.all` to `false` and `plugin.scan.Acrobat` to `99.0` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml");
```

The trick is to add the PDF MIME to the **plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types** preference.

This worked for Firefox 26.